# Pass parameter to controller JS (Kendo Datasource)

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi looking for any resource or direction as I am very new to Kendo and JS. I have a js calling the controller but I need to pass in a parameter to the controller. any suggestion

```
//js
     var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: ("myController/GetComboBoxItems"),//Need to pass the value parameter to controller
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data"
                }
            }
        });

//C#
        public async Task<IActionResult> myController([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,string value)
```

Comment: Have you try `read: ("myController/GetComboBoxItems?value=whatever")`?

Comment: Set the `data` property of read.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `data` property of read. It is optional value and pass to the remote service if defined.

```
//js
     var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                       url: "myController/GetComboBoxItems",
                       data: {value : <<Enter the value here>>} //Enter the value here.
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data"
                }
            }
        });

C#
public async Task<IActionResult> myController([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,string value)
```

You can read about at telerik documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read).